# How to stop AVPlayer Ios and remove the periodicTimeObserverForInterval

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm having a little difficulty stopping AVPlayer.

I have a method that records and plays music simultaneously. I'm using AVPlayer to play the music because I want to use the addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval Function.  I have it set up as follows:

```
    - (IBAction) recordVoice:(id)sender {
    if(!recorder.isRecording){

    //set up the file name to record to
    NSString *recordingLocation = [self createFileName];
    recordingName = recordingLocation;
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject],
                               recordingLocation, nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    recordingURL = outputFileURL;

    // Setup audio session
    session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                   error:nil];

    // Define the recording settings to record as m4a
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];
    [recorder record];


    // find which song to play and initiate an AVPlayer to play it
    NSString *playerLocation = self.TitleLabel.text;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:playerLocation ofType:@"m4a"];
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
        lastTime = nil;

    //check where the player is at and update the song lines accordingly
    [player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(3, 10) queue:NULL usingBlock:^(CMTime time){
            NSTimeInterval seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
            for (NSDictionary *item in robotR33) {
                NSNumber *time = item[@"time"];
                if ( seconds > [time doubleValue] && [time doubleValue] >= [lastTime doubleValue] ) {
                    lastTime = @(seconds);
                    NSString *str = item[@"line"];
                    [self nextLine:str];
                };
            }
        }];
        [player play];

    [_recordButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"micRecording.gif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else{
        [recorder stop];
        player = nil;
        [session setActive:NO error:nil];
    }   
}
```

If the recorder is not recording I set up both a new recorder AVAudioRecorder and an AVPlayer.  In the AVPlayer I set up an AddPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval which updates the UI based on the position of the player.

If the recorder is recording I stop the recorder and I set the player to nil.  This stops the audio from playing but I notice that the addPeriodicTimeObserverInterval is still running because the UI continues to update.  Should I destroy the AVPlayer altogether and if so how should I do that?  Many thanks in advance.

Also as an aside, I have a warning inside the addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval block.  I am looping over an Array called robotR33.  Xcode tells me that 'Capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle".  Could this be part of my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When finished playing the observer needs to be removed from the player.

Adding `[player removeTimeObserver:self.timeObserver]` works.

Comment: As for the compiler warning for strong self, you need a weak reference to self which you use inside your block.  You can do the following; just before the addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval method, add the following;   __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self; Then inside the block, replace [self nextLine:str] with [weakSelf nextLine:str];

Comment: What is `self.timeObserver`? This was not explained.